# ¿Cómo evitar que el teclado virtual reajuste el tamaño de la vista en un UIPopoverController?

Tags: ios

Así es como he creado el popover en el view controller de la aplicación:

```
if (!_suggestionsPopover) {
    UIViewController *suggestionsViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Suggestions"];
    _suggestionsPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:suggestionsViewController];
    _suggestionsPopover.delegate = self;
    _suggestionsPopover.passthroughViews = @[_searchField];
}

[_suggestionsPopover presentPopoverFromRect:_searchField.frame
                                     inView:self.view
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                   animated:YES];
```

El view controller del popover es creado desde el storyboard principal usando el Storyboard ID. La vista del popover tiene un tamaño suficientemente grande en su storyboard como para abarcar casi toda la pantalla.

El problema es que cuando el teclado virtual aparece el tamaño del popover es reajustado para hacerlo mas pequeño de modo que no obstruya la vista del teclado.

**Editado:**

Así es como debería lucir la vista del popover si el usuario toca el campo de búsqueda (en la parte superior donde dice "Search")

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si el usuario toca la pantalla en la lista de sugerencias para mover el scroll, el teclado se oculta mostrando toda la lista de sugerencias en el popover. Esa manera de mostrar la lista de sugerencias de la búsqueda es la que usa Safari en iOS y que quiero replicar en mi aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el botón/vista que muestra el popover se sigue viendo una vez el teclado aparece o queda oculta?

Comment: @mhergon Edité la pregunta para colocar la imagen de como debería aparecer el popover.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente, lo mejor que puedes hacer es seguir esta respuesta:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5733411/685375

Básicamente se trata de detectar cuando aparece el teclado y volver a presentar el popover para que se autoajuste.

La otra opción, es detectar el scroll en la vista y ocultar el teclado.

Comment: Ya veo, allí reajustan el tamaño del popover a sus dimensiones originales cuando el teclado se oculta, que es bueno para evitar que el sistema lo reposicione arbitrariamente. Lo que yo quisiera es poder evitar también que el tamaño del popover cambie del todo cuando el teclado aparece, tal y como el tamaño de la vista de las sugerencias de búsqueda en Safari para iOS permanece inmutable sin importar si el teclado es visible o no.

Comment: @rraallvv es lo mismo, pero al revés. Cuando detectas el teclado, haces un resize en caso de que le cambie el tamaño. O dicho de otra forma, muestra otra vez el popover cuando detectes el teclado.